# Char compare Function in C

Tags: c

There some times when I realy need to compare two CHARs and from what I know there is no Function in C to compare two CHARs (maybe i'm wrong) and because of this I decided to write one of my own.
The function is working fine but I'm not sure if is also ok, or there are some problems.
I decided to ask you about this if my function is ok.
Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int chrcmp(const char chr1, const char chr2);

int main(void){
    char firstChar = 'a';
    char secondChar = 'a';

    if( chrcmp( firstChar, secondChar ) == 0 ){
        printf("We have a Match\n");
    }else{
        printf("There was no match Found.\n");
        printf("%c",chrcmp(firstChar, secondChar));
    }

    return 0;
}

int chrcmp(const char chr1, const char chr2){
    size_t lenght1, lenght2;

    char s1[2] = {chr1 , '\0'}; /* Convert chr1 to string */
    char s2[2] = {chr2 , '\0'}; /* Convert chr2 to string */

    lenght1 = strlen(s1); /* Store lenght of first String */
    lenght2 = strlen(s2); /* Store lenght of second String */

    if( lenght1 == 1 && lenght2 == 1){  /* Checking if both strings have the same size (1) */
        if( strcmp(s1,s2) == 0 ){     /* Compare both strings */
            return 0; /* Match Found! */
        }else{
            return 1; /*No Match!;*/
        }
    }else{
        return 1; /*To many chars Found!;*/
    }
}
```

If there are some problems, or if I did something wrong I have no ideeas.

Comment: Not related to your problem and actually a nitpick, but the word is `length`, not `lenght`.

Comment: English is not my own Language, but i think you allready notice that,

Comment: Yes I did, I'm not trying to criticize you or make you feel bad, just a friendly note so you know the right spelling in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `char` is actually an integer type. For arithmetical operations, that is promoted to `int`, so you can use normal integer comparison.

Note that whether `char` is signed or unsigned is *implementation defined*, so to make sure, you should always use `signed char` or `unsigned char` (recommended) if you do arithmetics (includes comparisons) on chars other than test for equality.

What you cannot do is compare two char **arrays**, such as

```
char ch[] = "Hello";
if ( ch == "Hello" )
    ...
```

For that you need `strncmp()` or `strcmp()`. Use the latter only if your are **absolutely** sure both strings are properly terminated!

Comment: just can you explain why we cannot do this `if ( ch == "Hello" )`

Comment: @Youssefmahmoed: Sorry for the late reply. I did not say we cannot do that. But that does not compare two arrays (what I wrote), but pointers (what I not even implied). In the way written, this is hardly usefull (because of the second one being a seperate literal).

Answer (score 3):

Uh...

Just do this:

```
char a = 'y';
char b = 'x';
if( a == b ) printf("Chars equal");
```

The `char` type in C (and C derivatives) is actually an integer type and has the full set of integer comparison operators defined for it: <, >, ==, !=, <=, >= in addition to the bitwise &, |, and ~ operators.

Answer (score 3):

> from what i know there is no Function in C to compare thow CHARs

That is incorrect. There is the equality operator `==` (as well as all the other comparison operators):

```
if (firstChar == secondChar) {
  /* chars are equal */
}
```

Comment: I know about it and i did use it, but in tought that is wrong comparing two CHARs useing ==.

Comment: @Michi What made you think that? Unless by "comparing" you mean something different to equality comparison.

Comment: I made a Menu with switch and i had to ask user for Y or N, and i was not sure if i can compare two chars using "==". I did not know that CHARS are interpreted like integers in this situations. So i decided to complicate things .....i guess.

Comment: @Michi `char` *are* integers. They can be used to store ASCII (or UTF-8) values, but really they're just integers.